# Compile into only one independent binary file

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core

I coded a simple program and I compiled it with `dotnet publish -c Release -r osx.10.11-x64`

It creates a binary file that works well but if I move this file somewhere else without the other files in the same directory, the program can't run:

`A fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.dylib could not be found at /Users/me/`

Is there any way to make the binary independent?
I remember on Windows and with .NET it was possible using ILMerge (but it uses `.dll` files, and not `.dylib`)

Comment: Usually all the older commands still work if you use the command line compiler.  A dll, library , and exe are all very similar in structure.  The only real difference between a dll and a exe is that an exe must have a main() while a dll it is optional.  A dll is really a newer version of the old Library where the dll first was used with Window95.  The old Library was a simple merge of obj where each method could be called from an executable.  The dll simply added a new wrapper around the old library format (a merge of the obj's).

Comment: I don't understand what is your point. How can it help me to merge the files generated by compilation and create only one independent executable file ?
I can't even try to use ILMerge because I use a Mac.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @jdweng This is an OSX question

Comment: @jdweng I tried to compile using `csc *.cs`, and when I run `./Program.exe` the terminal returns an error: `zsh: exec format error: ./Program.exe`. The program seems to not be compiled for OSX

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. .NET Core is still a modular system and by deploying a self-contained application, you essentially ship a copy of the entire runtime. While it is possible to use the new linker (in preview) to reduce the size of the managed assemblies (or use ILMerge to merge all managed assemblies), there are still native assets (the `.dylib`) files that are reference by name in the code.

There is a different runtime project - [CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) - which aims to create a single native executable by compiling the managed part ahead of time to machine code. This project is still under development.